# Is it possible to get raw files at BitBucket?

Tags: git, curl, github, bitbucket, wget

GitHub offers direct access to files in public repositories by using a link like `https://raw.github.com/user/repository/branch/filename`. Using a link like this and CURL or WGET I may get a file in a public repository easily.

I recently moved some repositories I had at GitHub to BitBucket, since BitBucket offers me five private repositories for FREE, and FREE always seemed a lovely word for me. But it happens that I'm missing this feature in my public BitBucket repositories.

Is there a similar feature at BitBucket?

If so, what is the format of the URL to get a file?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. `https://bitbucket.org/<account>/<repo-name>/raw/<commit-sha-or-HEAD>/<filename>`

For this repo: https://bitbucket.org/pedrorijo91/hello-slick/src

Choose a a file (LICENSE for instance): https://bitbucket.org/pedrorijo91/hello-slick/src/fe7cfe392d8090fececdf481ba3a9270bbe678dd/LICENSE?fileviewer=file-view-default

and now click on the RAW button: https://bitbucket.org/pedrorijo91/hello-slick/raw/fe7cfe392d8090fececdf481ba3a9270bbe678dd/LICENSE

It seems bitbucket always adds a SHA before the file. You can specify the commit or HEAD seems to work also: https://bitbucket.org/pedrorijo91/hello-slick/raw/HEAD/LICENSE

Comment: You can also use branch name, instead of `<commit-sha-or-HEAD>`.

Comment: Thanks and an update note: In our current bb installation 7.12.0 I get raw files with ...reponame/raw/path-to-file.

Comment: @samzmann can you please add example with some subfolders before the filename? where in this path to put subfolders after the repo-name?

Answer (score 5):

it is easy to get plain text of any file using curl.

curl --user userName https://FQDN/repo_name/**raw**/fileName -o fileName

for example:
URL for the target page in bitbucket:
https://bitbucket.myDomain.com/projects/repos/repo/**browse**/myFile

will end with the following curl request:
curl --user username https://bitbucket.myDomain.com/projects/repos/repo/**raw**/myFile -o targetFile

Comment: This worked for me on my private Bitbucket repo. I just had to include the SHA (or branch name) after `raw/` as in the other answer.

Comment: Works. To make this prompt free, I used curl -H "Authorization: Bearer *******"