# How to set resource from bitbucket in openAPI specification as $ref (URL Reference)

Tags: bitbucket, openapi

Can we set $ref :'Some Bitbucket URL' in openAPI specification?
If yes
Also how to add required username and password for bitbucket.
tried below but not working
$ref: 'https://username:password@resourceURL#/definitions/nameOfTheComponent'.

is there any additional change we need to do access URL Reference for accessing bitbucket URL ?
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/ does not have information about adding username password for url.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference files from **public** Bitbucket repositories by using [raw links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38163248/113116). Raw file links have the following format (assuming you use bitbucket.org):

```
https://bitbucket.org/<OWNER>/<REPO>/src/<BRANCH_NAME or HEAD or COMMIT_SHA>/<PATH_TO_FILE>
```

For example, you can reference the `Pet` schema from [this file](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/swagger-request-validator-core/src/test/resources/oai/v3/pet.yaml) as:

```yaml
$ref: 'https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/raw/master/swagger-request-validator-core/src/test/resources/oai/v3/pet.yaml#/components/schemas/Pet'
```

You cannot reference files from **private** Bitbucket repos. That's because programmatic access to private Bitbucket repositories requires [authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/intro/#authentication), and `$ref` doesn't have a mechanism to provide the credentials for authentication.

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying!! So only publicly available resources are candidates for referring in 'URL reference' when using bitbucket/github/any other server's resources in $ref?

Comment: @user2425109 Yes